# How to dynamically add widgets on a different screen depending on which button is pressed if the buttons were added dynamically as well?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

## The Problem

I'm attempting to create dynamic buttons tied to "pages" in my program. Each button and page inherits a name from a database that I have tied to the program. In this case, I'm having trouble adding widgets to a screen and changing to that screen on button press. So far, I'm able to implement dynamic buttons that could change the screen and receive variables for text but the widgets aren't being added or aren't showing up.

## The Code

Upon request, I recreated the code with the same problem my program was experiencing.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from functools import partial

kv = '''
ScreenManager
    ScreenOne:
    ScreenTwo:
    ScreenThree:
    
<ScreenOne>:
    
    ScrollView:
    
        MDGridLayout:
            id: screen_one
            cols: 1
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: "40dp"
            MDFlatButton:
                text: "Next Page"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen 2'
        
<ScreenTwo>:
    name: 'Screen 2'
    on_pre_enter: root.on_load()
    ScrollView:
    
        MDGridLayout:
            id: screen_two
            cols: 1
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: "40dp"
<ScreenThree>:
    name: 'Screen 3'
    ScrollView:
    
        MDGridLayout:
            id: screen_three
            cols: 1
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: "40dp"
'''
sm = ScreenManager()

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass




class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def on_load(self):
        name_list = ['Page 1', 'Page 2', 'Page 3']
        button_list = []
        for x in name_list:
            page_button = MDRectangleFlatButton(text = x, theme_text_color = "Custom")
            button_list.append(page_button)
        for x in button_list:
            x.bind(on_press = partial(self.load_home, x.text))
            self.ids.screen_two.add_widget(x)
            
            
            
    def load_home(self, name, *largs):
        self.manager.current = 'Screen 3'
        Screen3 = ScreenThree()
        Screen3.on_load(name)
        
        
        
        
    def on_leave(self):
        self.ids.screen_two.clear_widgets()
        
        
# Below is the particular code I'm having trouble with. It's supposed
# to display a page with a button with the same name as the button
# that sends you to Screen Three. However, the button is not showing up.
class ScreenThree(Screen):
    def on_load(self, name, *kwargs):
        test_button = MDRectangleFlatButton(text = name, theme_text_color = "Custom")
        self.ids.screen_three.add_widget(test_button)

sm.add_widget(ScreenOne(name="Screen 1"))
sm.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name="Screen 2"))
sm.add_widget(ScreenThree(name="Screen 3"))

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return screen


TestApp().run()
```

All help, tips, and solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Turns out, I can add the buttons from the same method as ScreenTwo's load_home() method by giving each screen ids via screenmanager in the kivy code:

```
ScreenManager
    ScreenOne:
        id: one
    ScreenTwo:
        id: two
    ScreenThree:
        id: three
```

And then use the add_widget function in the load_home() method:

```py
def load_home(self, name, *largs):
        test_button = MDRectangleFlatButton(text = name, theme_text_color = "Custom")
        self.manager.ids.three.ids.screen_three.add_widget(test_button)
        self.manager.current = 'Screen 3'
```